# What is the true difference between CompareAndSet and IncrementAndGet?

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing

I am trying to understand the true difference between `CAS (CompareAndSet)` and `IncrementAndGet` when using Atomic Variables.  I understand that CAS is a non-blocking method to allow for multiple threads to try to optimistically change a variable.  If it fails, it tries again.  What I don't understand is why use that if you can use `IncrementAndGet`? It seems like it does the same basic functionality besides being able to say with `CAS`: `CAS(235, 300)` where `IncrementAndGet` can only add one to the current value while `CAS` can have whatever it wants inside the expected value parameter.

Thank you!

Comment: They do completely different things. `compareAndSet` is a **conditional** assignment. `incrementAndGet` is a nonconditional update and return.

Comment: The difference is that they are not the same. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`incrementAndGet` is not (necessarily) a parallel instruction to CAS. It's a construct built *on top of* the native CAS functionality. Take a look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.java#AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet%28%29)* to see how this works:

```
/**
 * Atomically increments by one the current value.
 *
 * @return the updated value
 */
public final int incrementAndGet() {
    for (;;) {
        int current = get();
        int next = current + 1;
        if (compareAndSet(current, next))
            return next;
    }
}
```

<sub>*I'm using the Java 7 version for simplicity's sake, but Java 8 is the same idea.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

> What is the true difference between CompareAndSet and IncrementAndGet?

The difference is that they do different things.  This is clear from the description in your question.  Even the names of the methods:

- one is conditional and the other is unconditional
- one is a set operation and the other is an increment operation.

> What I don't understand is why use that if you can use IncrementAndGet?

For example, you would use it if you simply want to increment the atomic number.  It would be the equivalent of this ...

```
    int newValue = ++atomicCount;
```

... if there was a truly atomic primitive type in Java.  (There isn't.)